# Add the team membership to the user who is already member of other project using RallyAPI

Tags: rally, arrays, java

Consider **USER1** is already team member of **Project1** & **Project 2**. I would like to make him team member to **Project 3**. Following part of my code adds the **USER1** to **Project 3** but removes team membership in **Project 1** & **Project 2**

I just want the User1 to be added to Project 3 along with Project1 & Project 2.Could someone please advise?

Thanks

```
                 JsonArray TeamMemberships = new JsonArray();

                // add or remove projects for user

                TeamMemberships.add(projectObj);

                // Setup update fields/values for Team Membership
                JsonObject updateUserTeamMembershipObj = new JsonObject();
                updateUserTeamMembershipObj.add("TeamMemberships", TeamMemberships);

                UpdateRequest updateTeamMembershipsRequest = new UpdateRequest(userRef, updateUserTeamMembershipObj);
                UpdateResponse updateTeamMembershipResponse = restApi.update(updateTeamMembershipsRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to java, but generally for WS API v2.0, using a browser REST client:

If currently teammembership has two projects, e.g.
{"/project/123"},{"_ref":"/project/456"}

add another project `/project/789` using this endpoint:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/777/teammemberships/add?key=cb9473f7-.....
```

and payload:

```
{
"CollectionItems":[
{"_ref":"/project/789"}
]}
```

successfully updates the collection without removing the pre-existing elements, so it looks like one does not have to include `{"/project/123"},{"_ref":"/project/456"}` in the CollectionItems, at least when using a rest client.

Comment: Couldn't I do this using Java API?

Comment: I don't have a ready example of doing it in Java, but I verified in Crome rest client that it is not necessary to include pre-existing elements in the CollectionItems in order to add a new element.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'm trying with the code above, but it removes the team membership for other projects when I try to add in new project.If you get a chance, please try. Thanks